# Running two jobs with Quartz in Java

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler, job-scheduling

I have Quartz coded as follows and the first job runs perfectly:

```
JobDetail jd = null;
CronTrigger ct = null;   
jd = new JobDetail("Job1", "Group1",  Job1.class);
ct = new CronTrigger("cronTrigger1","Group1","0/5 * * * * ?");
scheduler.scheduleJob(jd, ct);
jd = new JobDetail("Job2", "Group2",  Job2.class);
ct = new CronTrigger("cronTrigger2","Group2","0/20 * * * * ?");
scheduler.scheduleJob(jd, ct);
```

But I'm finding that Job2, which is a completely separate job to Job1, will not execute.

The scheduler is started using a listener in Java. I've also tried using scheduler.addJob(jd, true); but nothing changes. I'm running Java through a JVM on windows 7.

Answer (score 1):

How do you know the job does not run? If you substitute `Job1.class` for `Job2.class`, does it still fail? When you swap order in which they're added to scheduler, or only leave `Job2`? Or if you strip down `Job2` to only print a message to console?

I suspect `Job2` execution dies with an exception.

Comment: I've tried changing the ordering of the jobs and have tried numerous debug messages throughout both. but only job 1 runs.

Comment: So there must be a bug within Job2. Wrap everything in execute() in try { ... } catch(Throwable t) { t.printStackTrace(); } and see what happens.

Comment: Bad logic on my part. Mea culpa! And now to sort out the cron timings so that one job runs on the hour and the other on the half hour.

Comment: "30 * * * * ?" (1:30, 2:30, 3:30), "0 * * * * ?" (1:00, 2:00, 3:00), "*/30 * * * * ?" (1:00, 1:30, 2:00, 2:30), "15,45 * * * * ?" (1:15, 1:45, 2:15)

Comment: If "30 * * * * ?" runs the job half past every hour, does "0 * * * * ?" run on the hour? Thanks.

Comment: Err, sorry for the typo. Actually, that should be "0 30 * * * ?" and "0 0 * * * ?". See also http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/docs/tutorial/TutorialLesson06.html and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CRON_expression or just Google cron expression.

Comment: @Konrad Garus: Many thanks. Would you have any idea about: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3185221/running-a-quartz-job-with-java-class-name-stored-in-database